# Byte conversion back to Image

Tags: vb.net, type-conversion, byte, arrays

I'm trying to convert the bytes in plr.PlayerImage back into an image for the picturebox.

However, Method 1 returns the error "Value of type Byte cannot be converted to 1-dimensional array of Byte" on plr.PlayerImage.

Method 2 provides the error message "Conversion from type Byte() to type Byte is not valid".

Method 1 works when used in a separate sub where I retrieve the data from the database, but won't work in my new sub:

```
Dim pictureData As Byte() = DirectCast(drResult("PlayerImage"), Byte())

                            Dim picture As Image = Nothing

                            'Create a stream in memory containing the bytes that comprise the image.
                            Using stream As New IO.MemoryStream(pictureData)
                                'Read the stream and create an Image object from the data.'
                                picture = Image.FromStream(stream)
                            End Using

                            UC_Menu_Scout1.PictureBox1.Image = picture
```

Current Code:

```
Private Sub fillPlayerInfo()

            For Each plr As Player In getAllPlayers()

                If lbPlayers.SelectedItem.PlayerID = plr.PlayerID Then

                    txtFirstName.Text = plr.PlayerFirstName
                    txtSurname.Text = plr.PlayerLastName
                    txtPlaceOfBirth.Text = plr.PlaceOfBirth
                    cmbClub.SelectedValue = plr.ClubID
                    dtpDOB.Value = plr.DOB

                    '**********Method 1*********************************************
                    Dim pictureData As Byte() = DirectCast(plr.PlayerImage, Byte())
                    Dim picture As Image = Nothing

                    'Create a stream in memory containing the bytes that comprise the image.
                    Using stream As New IO.MemoryStream(pictureData)
                        'Read the stream and create an Image object from the data.
                        picture = Image.FromStream(stream)
                    End Using

                    '**********Method 2*********************************************
                    Dim ms As New IO.MemoryStream(plr.PlayerImage)
                    Dim returnImage As Image = Image.FromStream(ms)

                    pcbEditPlayer.Image = returnImage

                End If
            Next

        End Sub
```

Comment: In method 2 you forgot to wrap your "plr.PlayerImage" in a Byte(). For example this: plr.PlayerImage should be: Ctype(plr.PlayerImage, Byte()) going in your memory stream.

Comment: I tried this: Dim ms As New IO.MemoryStream(CType(plr.PlayerImage, Byte())), but I still get the error "Value of type Byte cannot be converted to 1-dimensional array of Byte" on plr.PlayerImage

Comment: Is playerImage defined as byte?

Comment: Yes, in my Player class it's defined as Byte

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As said in my comment from above, your not casting your property in the memory stream you have created. Also if `plr.PlayerImage` is not defined as `Byte()` you will get an exception.

Here's what it may look like...

```
 Public Property PlayerImage As Byte()
```

***Here's what you currently have***...

```
  Dim ms As New IO.MemoryStream(plr.PlayerImage) 'This is wrong...
  Dim returnImage As Image = Image.FromStream(ms)
  pcbEditPlayer.Image = returnImage
```

***It should be like***...

```
 Dim ms As New IO.MemoryStream(CType(plr.PlayerImage, Byte())) 'This is correct...
 Dim returnImage As Image = Image.FromStream(ms)
 pcbEditPlayer.Image = returnImage
```

Comment: If it helps, when I retrieve PlayerImage: .PlayerImage = drResult("PlayerImage") .PlayerImage is definitely defined as Byte

Comment: Solved! Although my property was defined as Byte, I changed it to Byte() and it worked! Thank you for your help

Comment: I mentioned this in my post (and first comment), you have to have the () for it to be a byte array. Also the consensus is if the post helped please mark as answered.